# General solution for a second order linear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(x)y\,,
\end{equation}
is it somehow possible to find an expression for $y$ in terms of $f(x)$ in the interval $x>0$, assuming that we know that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \sim 1/x^2$ and  $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) \sim 1/x^2$ and that $f(x)$ and $y$ are everywhere smooth.

Comment: You mean like the WKB approximation? In general there is no closed solution, just check the standard examples $f(x)=x$ (Airy equation) and $f(x)=x^2$ (some Bessel functions). Of course with $f(x)=1/x^2$ you get an Euler-Cauchy equation with basis solutions $x^m$, where $m^2-m-1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible! In some interval, say $[10, 15]$ this is the general problem of solving $y^{\prime\prime}=f(x)y$ which is as general as 
$$y^{\prime\prime}+P(x)y^\prime+Q(x)y=R(x)$$
And this can not be solved in general. (I'm not sure if it's a conjecture or already proved that you can't solve this.)

You can definitely come up with asymptotic approximations though. And for the special case $y^{\prime\prime}-\frac{y}{x^2}=0$ this has the sol'n
$y=a_+x^{n_+}+a_-x^{n_-} $
With $n_\pm$ being the roots of
$$n^2-n-1=0$$